# Is there something similar to JavaScript's getElementById() in ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to do something similar to getElementById(), but I am having trouble finding something like that in ampscript.

I have only found:

```
%%=Substring('abc',1,2)=%%
```

I am trying to manipulate content if something happens.

Comment: To make it easier for other users to see that there is a correct answer to your question, please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

AMPscript isn't rendered on the client, so content manipulation triggered by events isn't possible. So you can only manipulate/generate content on render of the page.

If you want to display different content blocks based on data (variable values) you can use simple if statements as described in [AMPscript 201](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_201/)

For further information and an introduction to AMPscript check out the documentation at [help.marketingcloud.com](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/)